iterate through array with while
I'm stuck with the following while loop.
EDIT: The goal of the program is to iterate through an array completly from start to end as mentioned in the title.
For that I tried to use the while loop
while(*rtn)

is considered false as long as the first value is zero (see example 0 below) so the program doesn't enter the while loop. If I change the first value to be non zero (example 1) the program will enter the while loop. If I change the value assignment so that the fifth element will be zero (example 2) the while loop will stop at the fifth element. The for loop works as expected.
    size_t sz = 100 ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    int *rtn = malloc(sz*sizeof(int));                                                                                                                             
    int cnt ;                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                   
    for(cnt = 0 ; cnt < sz ; cnt++){                                                                                                                               
 EXAMPLE 0 rtn[cnt] = cnt*2 ;        // First value of array is 0                                                                                                                                     
 EXAMPLE 1 rtn[cnt] = cnt*2 + 5 ;    // first value of array is non zero                                                                                                                                     
 EXAMPLE 2 rtn[cnt] = 5 - cnt ;      // fifth value will be 0                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    cnt=0 ;                                                                                                                                                        
    printf("\n---WHILE LOOP---\n") ;                                                                                                                               
    while(*rtn){                                                                                                                                                   
        printf("%3d - %4d\n",cnt, *rtn) ;                                                                                                                          
        cnt++ ;                                                                                                                                                    
        rtn++ ;                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                   
    printf("\n---FOR LOOP---\n") ;                                                                                                                                 
    for(cnt = 0 ; cnt < 10 ; cnt ++){                                                                                                                              
        printf("%3d - %4d\n", cnt, rtn[cnt]) ;                                                                                                                     
    }                                               
   

I thought the while loop is testing for the NULL pointer not for 0 which obviously can be a valid value!?
Also if i change the while loop to
while(rtn){
...
}

it will just go through the complete memory (?) and end with an error. So in essence the while loop is not a valid tool to iterate through an int array?!

Your question doesn't really make sense. Are you interested in iterating over each element of the array or are you interested in iterating until you see a "false" value (including 0 or NULL)? It would make sense to do one or the other. If you want to iterate over each element then either use the for loop or make a while loop that checks if cnt reached the end

In C, a zero integer is considered false, so the loop will terminate as soon as it encounters the first zero in the array.

Why not have the while loop check if the pointer is null, then? Unless doing direct comparisons to NULL is discouraged in C.

Please be aware that while(*rtn) is equivalent to while (rtn[0] != 0). And that if there are no 0 in the array, your loop will go out of bounds and you will have undefined behavior.

@FrasherGray Technically, if rtn is not a null-pointer to begin with, it will never become a null-pointer. Unless the code explicitly do an rnt = NULL assignment.

@sake What's worse, when you get to your for loop you no longer have the original value of rtn. It's lost in the while loop. So you will go even further out of bounds there.

Ooh, yeah that's mb. From what I understand, he just wants a way to check if the pointer is still within allocated memory?

As for solving the problem, a for loop like for (a; b; c) { d; } is equivalent to { a; while (b) { d; c; } }. So you you can still use a while loop like that. Or keep track of the end of the allocated memory, like int *end = rtn + cnt; and then while (rtn < end)

Please, clarify the question, and provide reproducible code. What are you really trying to do? What (reproducible) code are you running and doesn't behave as you'd expect? What were you expecting?

Your understanding of the behavior of the while (*rtn) loop in C is correct. The loop condition while (*rtn) evaluates the value pointed to by rtn. If the value is zero, it is considered false and the loop terminates. This is why, in your examples:

Example 0: The first value is zero, so the loop never starts.
Example 1: The first value is non-zero, so the loop starts and continues until it encounters a zero.
Example 2: The loop stops at the fifth element, which is zero.

The while (*rtn) loop is indeed checking for the value pointed to by rtn, not for a NULL pointer.
The condition while (*rtn) is not suitable for iterating through an array if any element of the array can be zero. It stops as soon as it encounters the first zero, which might not be the end of the array.
To iterate through the entire array, you can use a for loop or a while loop with an explicit counter. Here’s how you can do it using a for loop:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    size_t sz = 100;
    int *rtn = malloc(sz * sizeof(int));
    int cnt;

    // Example 0: First value of array is 0
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < sz; cnt++) {
        rtn[cnt] = cnt * 2;
    }

    // Example 1: First value of array is non-zero
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < sz; cnt++) {
        rtn[cnt] = cnt * 2 + 5;
    }

    // Example 2: Fifth value will be 0
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < sz; cnt++) {
        rtn[cnt] = 5 - cnt;
    }

    printf("\n---WHILE LOOP---\n");
    cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < sz) {
        printf("%3d - %4d\n", cnt, rtn[cnt]);
        cnt++;
    }

    printf("\n---FOR LOOP---\n");
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < 10; cnt++) {
        printf("%3d - %4d\n", cnt, rtn[cnt]);
    }

    free(rtn);
    return 0;
}

Explanation:

Allocate memory for the array rtn.
Populate the array with values based on your examples.
Use a while loop with an explicit counter to iterate through the entire array.
Use a for loop to print the first 10 elements of the array.

By using a counter in the while loop (while (cnt < sz)), you ensure that you iterate through the entire array, regardless of the values it contains.

In addition to the other answers - you can stop the loop by creating a pointer to the end of the array and then having your loop check when it reaches the end, eg:
size_t sz = 100;
int *rtn = malloc(sz*sizeof(int));
int *end = rtn + sz;

...                                                                              

printf("\n---WHILE LOOP---\n");
while (rtn < end) {
    ...
    ++rtn;
}

On a side note: you are creating a memory leak by modifying the pointer that malloc() returns.  You need to free() the array when you are done using it.  So you should use a different pointer to iterate the array, eg:
int *arr = malloc(...);
...

printf("\n---WHILE LOOP---\n");
int *rtn = arr;
while (...) {
    ...
    ++rtn;
}

...

free(arr);


rtn < end is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

It is not clear what you are asking in your question but there is nothing wrong with using while loops or for loops for either of the tasks you mention. Below are examples of using either one to iterate over every element. There also are examples of using either one to iterate until a "false" element is found (can go out of bounds if there is no "false" element). There also is an example of a while loop that accomplishes the same thing with the syntax from your question
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int sz = 5; // I made this smaller for my example
    int* rtn = malloc(sz * sizeof(int));
    int cnt;

    // Populate some random data
    rtn[0] = 3;
    rtn[1] = 2;
    rtn[2] = 0;
    rtn[3] = 1;
    rtn[4] = 4;

    // If your goal is to iterate over every element this works
    printf("For every element\n");
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < sz; cnt++) {
        printf("%d\n", rtn[cnt]);
    }

    // If your goal is to iterate over every element this works too
    printf("While every element\n");
    cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < sz) {
        printf("%d\n", rtn[cnt]);
        cnt++;
    }

    // If your goal is to iterate until you find a "false" element this does
    // that BUT it will go out of bounds if there is no "false" element
    printf("For until \"false\" element\n");
    for (cnt = 0; rtn[cnt]; cnt++) {
        printf("%d\n", rtn[cnt]);
    }

    // If your goal is to iterate until you find a "false" element this does
    // that too. It also will go out of bounds if there is no "false" element
    printf("While until \"false\" element\n");
    cnt = 0;
    while (rtn[cnt]) {
        printf("%d\n", rtn[cnt]);
        cnt++;
    }

    // Yet another way to do the exact same as the previous while loop
    printf("Another while until \"false\" element\n");
    while (*rtn) {
        printf("%d\n", *rtn);
        rtn++;
    }

    return 0;
}


thanks, was looking for a solution with while loop just to better understand pointer arithmerics
